# Convert type List<object> to 'T'

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to write a generic function:

```
private T Convert<T>(List<object> list) where T : new()
{
    if (typeof(T).IsArray)
    {
        T array = new T();
        // ... convert here
        return array;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, I know that the objects in `list` should be the same type as the array of `T`.  For example, if `T` is `System.Int32[]` then I'd expect the objects in `list` to all be `Int32`.

However, `T` is not always an array.  In other cases, it may be a value type or even some other reference type.

How can I convert this `List<object>` to `T` given these assumptions?

**UPDATE**

This seems to be working within a set of given assumptions:

```
private T Convert<T>(List<object> list)
{
    // ... code omitted for brevity

    if (typeof(T).IsArray)
    {
        // big assumption here
        Type elementType = Type.GetType(typeof(T).FullName.Replace("[]", string.Empty));

        Array array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, list.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            array.SetValue(list[i], i);
        }
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(array, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: Linq already has the `.Cast<T>()` method, which does the same thing.

Comment: If all the objects in the list are the same type, then what you likely want to do is convert a `List<T>` to a `T[]`. Then, the compiler could infer the type of `T` from the type of the `list` parameter. But, then again, you could just call `.ToArray()`

Comment: ...also, why do you have `List<object>` in your code at all? (Using `object` is somewhat of a code-smell: there's very, very few cases where using `object` as a type is a leigitimate solution). What problem are you _really_ trying to solve?

Comment: @Dai In this scenario, T could be a number of different things and is defined outside of the scope of this function.  The List<object> is being fed to this function from a database source.  If T is a value type, I expect a single value and convert it. But if T is an array, I expect 1..n values and need to return it as the T provided.

Comment: If T is an int array, i would expect that the result  should be a List<int[]>, not an List<int>. If T is an int, i would expect a List<int>.

Comment: @Paul What "database source" is using `object` and why? So far everything you've said suggests the system is poorly designed. (and even if you _really have to_ accept `List<object>` there's no reason to reimplement something Linq already does).

Comment: it's look like XY problem ,  can you provider your use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ancient [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0) to create an array of the desired type. (It's pretty much the only thing it is good for.)

```
private T Convert<T>(List<object> list) 
{
    if (typeof(T).IsArray)
    {
        var tmp = new ArrayList(list);
        return (T)(object)tmp.ToArray(typeof(T).GetElementType());
    }
    return (T)list.First(); 
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1cWzXM)

Note: You should probably add some error handling, e.g. if the caller specified a `T` that doesn't make sense for the list.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work in my case because T is defined externally and could be a value type or an array type.  I need to sort that out in my function.

Comment: Not sure I follow. How do you plan to convert a `List<object>` to a value type?

Comment: Taking the first value only.  Think ExecuteScalar().

Comment: I see. See my revised answer.